# I want to update properties of an existing SharePoint document library file using REST API in c#.But I keep getting 403 error

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

```
            var updateFieldUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Requirements/docTwo.docx')/ListItemAllFields";
            var body = "{'__metadata': {'type':'Data.DocumentItem'},'Description':'My Title 3'}";
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Credentials = cred;
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
            //client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
            client.Headers["X-RequestDigest"] = GetFormDigestValueMetadata(webUrl, cred, cc);
            client.Headers["If-Match"] = "*";
            client.Headers["X-Http-Method"] = "PATCH";
            client.Proxy.Credentials = cred;

            var json = client.UploadString(updateFieldUrl, body);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a demo to update the Title property of the file in the document library.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var listName="doc1";
function UpdateListItem(){
var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
        "Title": $("#UpdateListItemTxt").val()    
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items("+$("#UpdateListItemID").val()+")",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success');
            window.location.href=window.location.href;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}

// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "Item";
}    
</script>

<p>Update List Item By ID: <input id="UpdateListItemID" type="text" value="1"/><input id="UpdateListItemTxt" type="text" value="Test"/><input type="button" onclick="UpdateListItem()" value="Update"/></p>
```

The result as below:

[image]

[image]